# How to intercept window.location change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a way to attach some pre-processing to each assignment of the window.location. Is there a way to do this. I basically need to serialize some info, that will be used in the new location.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event to trigger your code to run prior to navigation... If you need something more specific (e.g., only navigations initiated in *your code*), then I recommend that you factor out code changing `window.location` into a separate function, and add a hook for your custom logic.

Comment: Does this work for single page apps?  In Angular and other SPA frameworks, the URL changes but the page doesn't unload/reload, so I wonder whether this event fires.

Comment: generally frameworks provide custom events to get hold of location changes

Comment: @CarlG, in single page apps, you can use `onhashchange` to register a handler if the url hash has changed.

Comment: I will be appending &Id with window.location.href. That won't be coming inside beforeunload. Is there a way I can find all events which alters the url

Answer (score 12):

You may want to look at Ben Nadel's post in regard to doing this, it may be exactly what you're looking for

[**Binding Events to non DOM objects with jQuery**](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1520-Binding-Events-To-Non-DOM-Objects-With-jQuery.htm)

His example in the post talks about creating an event handler that triggers a change event when `window.location` changes

Comment: In effect the solution seems to `setInterval` and check periodically.