# Detect AngularJS routing via core Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular JS Application, We can use either 'ngRoute' or 'ui-router' for routing. I creating a javascript function to detect Route Changes in AngularJS Application. I used to below to code for that.

```
window.onhashchange = function() { //code here }
```

But, It only detects the '#' (hash) based url, Ex: myurl.com/#home

If 'html5Mode' is enabled in AngularJS. The above code is not working. Please help me to detect the clean urls via  Javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073086/javascript-how-to-intercept-window-location-change Both answers worth exploring.

Comment: Why are you doing that? And not use the route/location change events?

Comment: I create a common javascript widget for angular js, thats why i am asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Inject a listener to angular

```
angular.element(
   document.querySelector('.ng-scope')
).scope().$root.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(route, next, current){ 
   console.log(next, current);
});
```

#### Find first angular node

- document.querySelector('.ng-scope')

#### Make it jqLite or jQuery(if exists) wrapped

- angular.element()

#### get the scope of the dom,

- .scope() //this could already be $rootScope

#### get $rootScope from scope to make sure

- $root

#### Listen a event

- .$on

#### This is where ngRoute start listening on

- $locationChangeStart

#### callback with route object and next url and current url.

- function(route, next, current) {}