# How to make sure setInterval to check URL changes only run once?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a piece of JavaScript code that checks if the URL has changes (Single-page application), then it fires an event. However, the library can be instantiated more than once which will be a problem when there's multiple timers checking the URL change. I'm not sure how to solve this problem without using global variable.

Here's the snippet.

```
(function() {
  var _oldURL = window.location.href;
  setInterval(function() {
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    console.log(currentURL);
    if (currentURL !== _oldURL) {
      console.log('Fire event');

      _oldURL = currentURL;
    }
  }, 1000);
})();
```

If I run this snippet multiple time, there will be more timers checking if the URL changes. So every time the URL has changed, Timer1 and Timer2 will fire the event causing double events. I've solved this problem by using global variable which I think it's the best solution. I'm not sure if there's any other ways to solve this?

Here's what I've done.

```
(function() {
  window._oldURL = window.location.href;
  setInterval(function() {
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    console.log(currentURL);
    if (currentURL !== window._oldURL) {
      console.log('Fire event');

      window._oldURL = currentURL;
    }
  }, 1000);
})();
```

Comment: set variable = setInterval; then when condition fulfilled clearInterval(variable);

Comment: If you want it to run only once, why not use `setTimeout` instead?

Comment: Try using modules and singleton for your TimerChecker. But better would be hook onto `beforeunload` event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073086/javascript-how-to-intercept-window-location-change

Comment: Is really the whole URL changing or just the hash? Because then you don't need your own event listener implementation, you can simply use [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange)

Comment: why are you using `setInterval` instead of `hashchange` and `popstate` events?

Comment: My apologies, I think my title of the question is wrong. What I want is to have only one timer even you have multiple setIntervals running. I'll close this question and open a new one with more clarification.