# JQuery URL change listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, typescript

How can I catch when the browser URL was changed?

I have the following scenario:
In my page I have an iframe when the user clicks inside the iframe the iframe content changes and the URL in the browser is changed via js. 
Nothing else will change outside the iframe (not even the iframe src).

There is any possibility to check if the URL was changed?

This is not working:

```
jQuery(window).on("hashchange", () => {

}
```

EDIT: I fixed this problem using our internal event bus after the URL was changed, but I still think that there are better solutions for this using already built in events...

Comment: Do you have access to the `javascript` which changes browser URL? can you describe how URL is changed? What is original URL, and what is changed URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073086/javascript-how-to-intercept-window-location-change

Comment: It is not duplicate by that post. I don't want to create any URL checker only if I have no more options.

Comment: _"JQuery URL change listener"_ , _"I don't want to create any URL checker only if I have no more options."_ ? Is requirement to attach an event listener to the `location.href`? Note, URL can be changed without directly setting at `location.href = "abc"`. An alternative approach to an event listener could possibly be use of `Proxy`. What is requirement?

Comment: I need a listener which checks if the URL was changed even if the hash was not. The browser URL is set by a JS what I can't share and the only changes in the DOM is inside of an Iframe so not in the page where my JS if running. I solved the problem by using an event bus. When the URL is changed I broadcast a message... but I'm sure that there is some better way to deal with this.

Comment: Have you read linked article at this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2073116/) at [Javascript: How to intercept window.location change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073086/javascript-how-to-intercept-window-location-change)?

Comment: Yes I read. I don't want to write a checker which checks for the changes from time to time. Instead of that I would like to use the already existing events like hashchange, onbeforeunload.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about because the `iframe` is changing the url but you can try using the `onbeforeunload` event: it should be fire when a window is about to unload resources.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  // ...
};
```

Keep in mind that the `hashchange` should only work when hash changes (not complete URL).

Comment: Exactly and that is the problem. The other problem can be that we are using CORS to communicate between the page and the Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Set session variable when the visitor clicks certain button.