# fail to override setter & getter of window.location

Tags: javascript, function, overriding, getter-setter, method-modifier

I want to change all links assigned to `window.location`. So I assume `location` has getter & setter . That's why i cloned it & then i override the real `window.location` :

```
  var clonedLocation=Object.assign({},window.location);


            Object.defineProperty( window, 'location', {
              get: function (f) {
                return clonedLocation;
               },
              set:function(o){
                if(typeof o==='string'){
                  o=o+'?id=1';
                }
                clonedLocation=o;
              }
            } );

        };
```

The expected behavior (if overriding done ) is , when you write :

```
window.location='/go';
```

The script should redirect you to `/go?id=1` NOT `/go`.

However the actual behavior is that this script redirects to `/go`

==> Thus, the `window.location` setter wasn't overridden ,

How to override the setter of `window.location`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073086/javascript-how-to-intercept-window-location-change

Comment: Regarding the former `AOP` tag, wrapping and reassigning already declared functionality (be it functions or methods) misses any aspect of _AOP_. Any language which wants to qualify for the latter has to provide abstraction levels for at least `Joinpoint`, `Advice` and `Aspect`. The use case described by the OP should be referred to as method modification, and JavaScript of cause is well suited for this scenario and could easily provide a complete `target`/`context` aware toolset of method modifiers like `around`, `before`, `after`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally` via `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript properties [can be defined](http://bjorn.tipling.com/advanced-objects-in-javascript) to have `configurable: false` indicating that they can not be redefined.

Attempt to redefine such property will result in an error like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: location
```

It is to be expected that properties on host objects are not configurable for security reasons.

You can verify this by checking the property descriptor:

[image: Property descriptor for location]

Comment: Actually, being a *host object* property it doesn't even need its `configurable` attribute to be set to `false` for acting unpredictable.

Comment: Yeah - very true. Not really relevant to this specific question, but having a generic way to detect if or not a property is configurable (which host objects also adhere to) helps consumer code use reflection to detect configurability instead of having to special case all the host objects.

Answer (score 0):

you're used to wrap window.location with another static class which could implement hooks (before and after):

take a look into [kaop](https://github.com/k1r0s/kaop)

```
Aspects.add(
  function op1(){
    console.log("operation one");
    var argument0 = meta.args[0];
    if(typeof argument0==='string'){
        argument0=argument0+'?id=1';
    }
  },
  function op2(){
    console.log("operation two");
  }
)

var DummyLocation = Class({
  set: ["op1", function(newUrl){
    location = newUrl;
  }, "op2"],
  get: [function(){
    return location;
  }]
})
```

Now you should use:

```
DummyLocation.set("/go");
```