# Possible to disable following links in javascript but enable all other interactions (through chrome plugin)

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a plugin that needs to operate on arbitrary sites, and needs to prevent the url from changing.

Using `e.preventDefault` works to prevent normal anchor links from changing the url.

However any active javascript event handlers on site can still update the url. Unless I'm severely mistaken using `e.stopImmediatePropagation` doesn't solve this issue, since there's no way to guarantee that 'my' event handler containing `e.stopImmediatePropagation`  is the first event handler being run. (Again, because I don't control the site)

Now I can prevent all clicks from happening by the 'hack' of placing a transparent element under the mouse on mousedown and remove it again on mouseup.

However, that prevents any other click-interaction that doesn't result in a url change. If at all possible I'd like to keep these interactions enabled.

Any solutions that help me get out of this conundrum?

Comment: You could swap out the `a` element for something that doesn't produce a navigation action, like a `span` when you want to disable it.  Hide the anchor, show the span, the reverse it when you want to enable it again.

Comment: Agreed that would solve most of it. However, there may be behavior/ handlers attached to `a` that don't result in a location change (e.g.: javascript dropdowns) which I'd like to keep intact if possible. Replacing `a` with another element removes those handlers as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073086/javascript-how-to-intercept-window-location-change - it doesnt stop form submittals, but you didnt ask about those :)

Comment: Since events are executed in the order they are attached, you could try removing all events ([list events](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16544813/74015)) and then attaching *your* handler, and then reattaching the previously attached events (try to preserve their attachment order).