# Hook window.location.* assignments and window.location.assign

Tags: javascript, hook

I'm trying to intercept `window.location.*` assignments and `window.location.assign` calls to change the url assigned before leaving is that possible?
when I try to redefine the property setter I get an error that I can't redefine it.
Is my only option is to proxy the page and statically replace all assignments to window.location with string replace?
Although I rather avoid it since javascript is funky and something like this could also be valid so I would have to keep track of all assignments:

```
var l = window.location;
var c = l;
var t = c.assign;
t('...');
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to intercept window.location change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073086/javascript-how-to-intercept-window-location-change)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have a proxy which serve any website I wish. It's hooking all ajax calls and all resource fetches and pass them through the proxy as-well. A problem arises when a script is trying to change the current location through `window.location` assignments and I need to intercept them to change the url to be passed through the proxy as-well. for example `window.location = 'http://www.google.com'` -> `window.location = 'http://proxy-server/?url=http://www.google.com'`

Comment: @Jorayen - Interesting!

Comment: @Jorayen, it looks like a few years have passed since this question, did you ever get a satisfactory solution?

Comment: @Locksleyu I've abandoned the project I was working on at the time, but the solution I went for at the time was analyze all the references to `window.location.*` with ast package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/abstract-syntax-tree and then replace all urls to a proxy. Also evaluating the code for dynamic js, can't remember what packages I used, but I went for something more lightweight than headless browser.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would to be to create your own location change provider where you could intercept the URL and make changes accordingly.  Your code could then always call your change provider rather than the standard window.location property.

Of coarse this would not work if you are in a situation where the code that is setting the location property is out of your control.

If the location setting code is out of your control, take a look at [Javascript: How to intercept window.location change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073086/javascript-how-to-intercept-window-location-change) where the `beforeunload` event is used.

Comment: I've tried the `beforeunload` event with writing to `window.location` in it but it seems to have no effect. I have some extent of control over the code, I have a proxy which servers any page through param and I serve the wanted webpage. Now I can do static replacement using regex of some sort to any assignment but that's not a good solution as I've stated in my op. Any other ideas?

Comment: There is this crazy idea... https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1520-binding-events-to-non-dom-objects-with-jquery.htm.  The example allows you to at least log the location change, but don't know if you would be able to actually change it.

Comment: It misses most of the time to check for url changes because of the async nature of pulling. And as long as I can't stop the current relocation, and make a new one to my proxy this method won't help too much :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can do this. As you've found, the `location` property on `window` is non-configurable (at least in Chrome and Firefox). And as you know, it's very special: If you attempt to write to it (e.g., to replace it with your own customized object), instead of replacing the property in the normal way, it will convert what you give it to a string and attempt to navigate there. Consequently, there's no way for you to replace `window.location` with your own thing: `Object.defineProperty` won't let you (because it's non-configurable), and assignment won't work.

That leaves you with the task of identifying all writes to `window.location` in the JavaScript code on the page, which is impossible in the general case. While you could find all `window.location` and `location` references, and static analysis would tell you (absent `eval` or `new Function`) whether those `window` and `location` variables are the globals, you would need to evaluate the code step-by-step to find the kind of thing you mentioned in your question, or even something simple like:

```
(function(w) {
    w.location = "https://stackoverflow.com";
})(this);
```

---

Completely changing the architecture of your solution, you could run a headless browser server-side and echo changes to its DOM to the client, intercepting all clicks and forwarding them to server-side code to pass to the headless browser. Which likely has its own significant challenges.

Comment: I was afraid you're going to say headless browser, I've started with this in my solution but dropped it since I wanted something more lightweight and elegant. Well I guess it's the only way unless I detect every possible assignment which is hell since people can crypt function call names for example :s

Comment: @Jorayen - Yeah, you can't detect that with just static analysis. :-(

Comment: Ok I didn't like the idea of headless browser since I can't tell when to return changes from the server to the client since I'll have to pull for changes in some cases like `setTimeout` calls, you could say I could hook it and know how long I should wait for all timers more or less before sending echoing an update but I think it just going deeper into the rabbit hole and makes things more complicated. But I thought of a plausible solution that I would like you to tell me what you think.
Statically analyzing all assignments to `window.location.* ` would be to hard as we've already said.

Comment: But Statically analyzing *all* assignments in any of the scripts running, meaning I would have to find assignments such as `object.property = ...` or `object[property] = ...` without caring for what `object` is or what `property` is, for example I don't care if I see something like `vfje_4[fjsh('dx')]`. After finding *all* assignments I would wrap them in a setter function of my own checking the *reference* of where the object and the property are pointing to and if for example the reference is same as `window.location` then we "intercepted" a write to a desirable property (`window.location`)

Comment: The setter would be something like: `setter(o, p) { if (window.location === o[p]) // bingo ...}`
And we would put a setter call in every assignment found by our static analysis.
What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Jorayen - I'm fairly sure you can't do this purely with static analysis; again, you'd have to run the code statement by statement. Consider this artificial and unlikely example: `var x = Math.random() < 0.5 ? ["lo", "tion", "ca"] : ["tion", "lo", "ca"]; /*...some time later...*/ var y; if (x[0][0] !== "l") { x.push(x.shift()); y = x.join(""); } else { y = x[0] + x[2] + x[1]; }` and then the code uses `window[y] = "...";` Some obfuscators do things almost that wild.

Comment: Yea I understand, but I think my approach should still work, just find all assignments (should be a simple regex) and replace them with the setter, so for your example the `window[y] = "..."` becomes `setter(window, y, '...')` (ofcourse the other assignment above are changed as-well but it doesn't really matter).
And inside the setter we have reference check for our desired object like so:
`setter(object, property, value) => {if (object[property] === window.location) {change value!}}`
Am I missing something here?Because I think it should work if I manage to replace all assignments

Comment: @Jorayen - You mean ***all*** assignments to everything everywhere? That sounds like a big challenge. Also, remember that `location = "..."` works too, so you have to handle that.

Comment: I've created an assignment regex here:
https://regex101.com/r/m8V4u9/2
I've tried to capture all possible ways of assignments I know, hopefully I didn't miss something.
It's not perfect in any case, like if someone were to write `location = 'http://google.com'fdsfdsf` it would capture `'http://google.com'fdsfdsf` inside the `rvalue` group, but since it's not a valid expression anyway and it'll cause an error while evaluation the running script then I'm fine with it.
I'll update when I have the server side part logic of using the regex and replacing all of the matches with the setter.